# SpriteKit: View is sometimes nil and causing crash

Tags: swift

In my game, when the player bumps into an enemy I call the `loseGame()` function. It is crashing on the `view!.presentScene(scene)` line with the error:

`"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value".`

The confusing part is that it crashes randomly and infrequently, for some reason the view is nil only sometimes and I have no other code touching the view. Ideas?

```
func loseGame() {
    let scene = GameScene(size: size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    view!.presentScene(scene)     // "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value".
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in an `if` statement, and log when `view` is nil. Look at your logs and try to establish a pattern, then find the issue and fix it:

```
func loseGame() {
    let scene = GameScene(size: size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    if view != nil
    {
        view!.presentScene(scene)     // "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value".
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog("View is nil")
    }
}
```